# Getting error compiling ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

I just pod installed this Podfile for a new project:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

def import_pods
    pod 'Mantle'
    pod 'LBBlurredImage'
    pod 'TSMessages'
    pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
end

target 'WeatherJoy2' do
    import_pods
    link_with 'WeatherJoy2'
end
```

pod install succeeeded but now getting the following errors on building the project:

```
/Users/ankit/Documents/WeatherJoy2/Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/NSObject+RACKVOWrapper.m:49:3: Unknown type name 'rac_propertyAttributes'; did you mean 'mtl_propertyAttributes'?
/Users/ankit/Documents/WeatherJoy2/Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/NSObject+RACKVOWrapper.m:49:40: Implicit declaration of function 'rac_copyPropertyAttributes' is invalid in C99

/Users/ankit/Documents/WeatherJoy2/Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/NSObject+RACKVOWrapper.m:49:27: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'mtl_propertyAttributes *' with an expression of type 'int'
```

There is nothing else in the project, it was a new project. I'm on xcode 6.2 and OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when using Mantle and ReactiveCocoa together. It appears to be caused by both pods having an `EXTRuntimeExtensions.h` header, which made ReactiveCocoa import the incompatible Mantle version of the header (with `mtl_` vs `rac_` function name prefixes).

In my case I fixed it by replacing each occurrence of `#import "EXTRuntimeExtensions.h"` in the ReactiveCocoa pod with `#import "../Objective-C/extobjc/EXTRuntimeExtensions.h"`

Comment: It isn't really a solution, because each time you'll run pod install it will be replaced, or where did you add it?

Comment: As @melbic said this shouldn't be a permanent solution. Only a bypass for the moment to unblock you. Ankit you should not mark this as the final solution

Comment: Yes, this is just a workaround - ideally I'd figure out what's causing the header conflict and resolve it, but for now to allow the project to build I have this in my Podfile to keep the workaround when running pod install:

```post_install { `find Pods/ReactiveCocoa -type f ! -name EXTRuntimeExtensions.m -exec sed -i '' 's/import "EXTRuntimeExtensions.h"/import "..\\/Objective-C\\/extobjc\\/EXTRuntimeExtensions.h"/g' {} \\;` }```

(Paths might differ depending on the exact commit of ReactiveCocoa)

Comment: I get linker error with this approach:

```Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mtl_executeCleanupBlock", referenced from:
      -[NSObject(RACKVOWrapper) rac_observeKeyPath:options:observer:block:] in NSObject+RACKVOWrapper.o
      ___84-[NSObject(RACPropertySubscribing) rac_valuesAndChangesForKeyPath:options:observer:]_block_invoke in NSObject+RACPropertySubscribing.o
      ___84-[NSObject(RACPropertySubscribing) rac_valuesAndChangesForKeyPath:options:observer:]_block_invoke39 in NSObject+RACPropertySubscribing.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64```

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can set ReactiveCocoa version less then 3.0.0. For example, version 2.5 is normally working with Mantle.

```
pod 'Mantle', "~> 2.0.2"
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', "~> 2.5"
```